# Set width to remainder of parent - dynamic width

Tags: html, css

I have 2 `div` inside a fixed-width container.

`div1` has a dynamic width, with a maximum of 50%. I want `div2` to fill the remainder of the containers width.

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="left"></div>

    <div id="right"></div>  

</div>
```

Here's an example on `jsfiddle`.

Fully expanded as supposed to: http://jsfiddle.net/RuD74/

Containers background visible due to `right` not expanding: http://jsfiddle.net/hgpcp/1/

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated JFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d5U96/2/

I see what you are trying to do. Instead, set the second div to have:

```
#right {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

By doing this, it takes up all available width that's left except for the space occupied by the first floated div. Hopefully this does what you need.

Comment: Using this the `children` of `#right`s width is not working. fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d5U96/

Comment: Updated my answer. Now, the `children` elements will resize accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

A other thing that you can use it that you set the minimum width of your red/left box to 50%. This depends on what you would like to do with it.

```
#left {
float: left;

min-width: 50%;
max-width: 50%;
height: 100%;

background-color: red;
```

With this your `div1` gets the minumum width of the helf of your block.
The only negative thing about this is, that you can't make it smaller in time, if you'd like.