# How to set left element to use the remainder of it's parent's width when right element has variable width?

Tags: css

I am working on a navigation bar that has a right section with contents that will vary in width and then I want the left section to take the remainder of the space. I found `display: inline-block;` sets the element width based on it's content, but I cannot get the left section to take the remainder of the space.

I found another question that shows how to do what I want if the right section was the remainder ([Set width to remainder of parent - dynamic width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20432533/set-width-to-remainder-of-parent-dynamic-width)) and tried to figure out how to use that concept the other way round, but the right section ends up going onto a second line.

Ultimately I am trying to do this with polymer core-toolbars, but I cannot even get this to work with a very simple example.

html:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">main</div>
  <div id="right">variable width content</div>
</div>
```

css (using linked example):

```
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 32px;   
}
#left {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
#right {
  float: right;
  max-width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

css (using inline-block):

```
#container div{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  height: 32px;   
}
#left {
  left: 0px;
  background-color: blue;
}
#right {
  right: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

[Linked example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blade1981m/002a96rx/)

[Inline-block fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blade1981m/8wqxu3uq/)

I am not tied to using either of these methods, this is just what I have been trying after reading several posts.

Comment: There are a few ways to do what you're looking for, what kind of browser support do you need?

Comment: This is going to be primarily viewed in chrome.

Comment: please show a DEMO...